# Whats the time complexity of the below code?

Tags: java, time-complexity

```
public class Solution{
    public static List< Integer > printDivisors(int n) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=1;i<=Math.sqrt(n);i++){
            if(n%i==0){
                list.add(i);
                if(n/i !=i)
                {
                    list.add(n/i);
                }
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(list);
        return list;
    }
}
```

I wrote this code to get all the divisors of a number for this i have used a Arraylist for storing all the divisor and then sorted the list using **Collections.sort(list)**. I am still trying to learn how to answer the time complexity of the code.What would be the time complexity of the code?

Comment: *O(N)* by inspection, ignoring the ArrayList and the sort. The second test is redundant, as is the second add. I don’t know who thinks this isn’t about software development, but it is.

Comment: A question: Which Stack Exchange site is best for Big O and related questions on working code. Is it Stack Overflow or one of the others?

Answer (score 1):

There's more to the problem than is obvious at first glance.

There are two parts to look at: The time complexity of the `for` loop, and that of the call to `Collections.sort (List list)`.

If the number of iterations of the `for` loop is measured, the loop will run in *n^0.5* iterations. That is "fractional power" time,
which is *O(n^c), 0 < c < 1*. That could also be expressed as *O(n^(1/c)), 1 < c*.

Each step within the block controlled by the loop is *O(1)*, so that doesn't change the time complexity. [*]

`Collections.sort (List list)` uses a comparison sort, which runs in *O(m log m)* time, where *m* is the size of `list`.  In this case, *m=f(n)*, where *f* is a function that returns the number of factors of *n*.

The math for that is beyond Old Dog Programmer. But, it's not possible for the `for` loop in the original question to put more than `2*Math.sqrt(n)` elements into `list`. Let's take that as the worst case, although the actual worst case would be smaller.

So, it looks like the sort will need *2√n * log2 (2*√n)* comparisons in the worst case. That should be *O(√n * log (√n))*.

In the "competition" between the loop and the sort, which dominates? Since *√n log √n > √n*, it's the sort.

So, your code runs in *O(√n log √n)* time complexity, or "fractional power times log of fractional power".

**Note**

Adding a single element to the end of an `ArrayList` is normally *O(1)*. Occasionally, the size of the list will equal the capacity. When that happens, to add another element, the list will have to be resized. That will take *O(s)* time, where *s* is the previous size. One could prevent resizing by changing `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();` to `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>((int) Math.sqrt(n)*2);`

Comment: Surely you can simplify log √n. And since you're talking about algorithm variations anyway, might as well suggest one that's simply O(√n).

Comment: Btw I found it irritating when you claimed *"comparison sort, which runs in O(n log n)"*. The sort's runtime depends on the length on the list, which you hadn't said anything about yet. Can't just say O(n log n) when we have no idea how n relates to the length of the list. If the list had length n^2, then sorting it would *not* be O(n log n) and your claim would be wrong. You'd better say *"runs in O(m log m), where m is the length of the list"*. And then discuss how large m is.

Comment: @KellyBundy Thank you for the feedback. In writing the original edition, I thought it would make the answer more interesting if I showed my erroneous thinking based on a quick look at the code, and then realizing my error.

Comment: Edits to the answer are welcome, especially corrections to the math.

Comment: Yeah, I figured you did that intentionally for that reason, I just don't think it works well when it's *erroneous*. When it's just *suboptimal*, I think it can work well and I've probably done that myself sometimes. That is, establish something suboptimal and then go "But wait! Actually...".

Comment: About the math (not confident enough to edit): [Apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Approximate_growth_rate?wprov=sfla1) the number of divisors is o(n^e) for any e > 0. So let's use n^(1/4). Then the sorting is `O(n^(1/4) log n^(1/4))` = `O(n^(1/4) log n)` = `O(n^(1/2) / n^(1/4) * log n)` and since n^(1/4) grows faster than log n, we have that sorting is O(n^(1/2)). And thus the loop and the sorting and the total are O(√n). But it would be simpler if they first collected only the small divisors and then added their large partners so it's sorted without sorting.